# Straight To PHD or work with an MA as part time professor?

Tags: united-states, job-search, cv

So I've recently applied for my PHD in Economics and have found a a couple job offers to be a part time professor at a college (not a university) which only require an Masters degree. The contract is for 10 months.

I'm debating whether or not it is beneficial to my  academic career to delay my PHD for the next year for the sake of this teaching position as i am currently under then belief that it will improve my CV.

Which one is a better option?

Comment: When you say you have found job offers, does that mean you have received offers? Or found opportunities?

Comment: @Dawn Found oppurtunities, I know someone at this particular college and he told me his department is hiring for introductory Microeconomics and Mathematics for Business and Economics.

Comment: Are you looking at the US?

Comment: @Dawn Yeah I am

Comment: Consider: Publishing is always a professor's primary job. Teaching is a secondary side-gig. Reason from there.

Answer (score 7):

This is an opinion question which is disfavored here. It is also a personal choice question which is also disfavored.

But I would think, in general, that there are better ways to start out on an academic career than with such a position. Unless money is a big issue, my advice, if I were your advisor, would be to get into the doctoral program now and try to pick up a bit of teaching experience as part of it.

But that is an opinion, worth just about exactly what you paid for it.

Comment: Yes, I agree here. My observation is that those hiring Econ professors would not consider you to be a better candidate if you took such a job pre-PhD. I also am guessing that they typically hire late-stage PhD candidates for these positions.

Comment: @Dawn can you explain why?

Comment: Econ departments typically care more about research than teaching. You will likely have opportunities to teach during a PhD. These are considered sufficient. There is diminishing marginal utility to additional teaching. The exception might be community colleges or liberal arts colleges that are lower ranked, but I can’t say for sure.

Comment: Note that most job market advice for aspiring economist faculty members doesn't even mention teaching. See here, and also the other advice he links to: https://chrisblattman.com/job-market/

Comment: +1 I would suggest editing out the first line and making it a comment on the question instead. The advice here is actually much more solid than you're giving it credit (the OP really should follow this).